# Compute the mean square error at the end of each iteration and plot the same in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron, mse

i have a dataset to classify, using perceptron learning rule . i've calculated the weight matrix but don't know how to plot MSE .{1 = [
1
1
],1 = [
0
0
]}, {2 = [
1
2
],2 = [
0
0
]}, {3 = [
2
−1
],3 = [
0
1
]}, {4 = [
2
0
],4 = [
0
1
]},
{5 = [
−1
2
],5 = [
1
0
]}, {6 = [
−2
1
],6 = [
1
0
]}, {7 = [
−1
−1
],7 = [
1
1
]}, {8 = [
−2
−2
],8 = [
1
1
]}.
This the dataset and w=[-2 0;0 -2],bias =[-1 0];

Answer (score 0):

calculate weight change corresponding to a neuron , and apply the changed weights to all other inputs and find the mse.

```
 P=[p1,p2,...]
for i=1:number of inputs

    ///change weights here

   for j=1:number of inputs
       a=f(net);
      error[j] =target[j] -a[j];

     
   end
   mse=error *error' / numel(error);
   

end
```